# Shadow cut off under UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, shadow

I'm trying to add some shadow under a UIView.

In `drawRect` I created a rounded rectangle bezier path and appended a curved arrow-like bottom part to it (blue stuff)

[image]

Here is the shadow's code :

```
...
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextAddPath(context, rectPath.CGPath);  // rectPath is the bezier
        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,shadowSize, 3.0, [[[UIColor blackColor]  colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]CGColor]);    
        CGContextFillPath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
...
```

As you can see, the shadow is cut off at the bottom, that's where the view's frame ends. Can I extend the shadow "outside" the frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `CALayer` shadow properties instead of drawing the shadow in `drawRect:`

- `shadowOpacity`
- `shadowRadius`
- `shadowOffset`
- `shadowColor`
- `shadowPath`

this can result in some performance issues, which you can reduce by using the `shadowPath` property.

Comment: Yes, i knew this way too, but I thought if I calculate my paths and draw the whole view in drawrect I could draw the shadow here too... Eventually, setting my bezier as the `shadowPath` solved this issue, so I'll accept your answer ( but if you know why isn't the `drawRect` method working, please enlighten me :D ) Thanks.

Comment: you could use drawRect, but you have to extend your views frame so it can render the whole shadow. This is, depending on your code design, more complicated than just using the `CALayer` shadow properties. `drawRect` or `CGContext` is something like a paper-page, you cant draw outside of you page.